# Boston Sitecore User Group: Introducing SitecoreUML

Tags: discussion, status-completed, community-event

- **Date/Time (local):** Wednesday, 6 December 2017 *at 6:30pm*
- **Date/Time (UTC):** Wednesday, 6 December 2017 *at 11:30pm*
- **Location:** Genuine, 500 Harrison Avenue, Boston, MA
- **Event Details:** [Meetup Details and RSVP](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-New-England/events/244514135/)
- **Contact:** [Meetup Organizers](https://www.meetup.com/Sitecore-User-Group-New-England)
- **Description:** Introducing SitecoreUML, by Zachary Kniebel. SitecoreUML is a productivity tool that enables architects to create Sitecore templates directly from their UML diagrams, as well as export an existing Sitecore solution’s template architecture and generate UML diagrams from it. It's great for creating template architectures, auditing existing architectures, and creating detailed documentation that can be updated in just two clicks!